# Чтение файла с ftp - сервера без скачивания

Tags: c#, файлы, ftp

Есть FTP-сервер и на сервере лежат файлы. Как можно их читать без скачивания на компьютер? Файлы много весят, скачивание происходит очень долго, а планируется обрабатывать много таких файлов.

Comment: чтение и скачивание - это одно и то же. файл должен же как то оказаться у вас на компьютере, значит он должен пройти по сети

Comment: только качать.. или добавить сервис на сервер который по запросу будет отдавать порцию данных с файла - сомнительное решение. И чтоб ускорить обработку асинхронно обрабатывай файлы

Comment: А что для вас означает «читать»? Расскажите подробнее о том, какая у вас задача. _Может быть_, вам достаточно скачивать файлы не целиком, а по фрагментам. Или может быть, вам нужен лишь список файлов?

Comment: Будет организован поиск по файлам с расширением .nc c этого ftp-сервера - ftp://eclipse.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/seawinds/SI/uv/daily/netcdf. Задаются даты (начало, конец), на которые нужны данные, координаты - широта, долгота. Данные из файлов нужны не все, а только те, которые удовлетворяют условию поиска (широта, долгота).

Comment: Если вам нужен быстрый поиск по этим данным, до лучше их скачать, и проиндексировать, т.е. сделать свою базу, и искать уже в ней. Да, нужно будет забирать свежие данные и добавлять их в базу, но это будет относительно быстрая операция.

Comment: Почитайте про докачку файлов. это упрощает чтение больших файлов. Команда REST например тут https://moodle.kstu.ru/mod/page/view.php?id=80 Если чтение файлов "оборвалось" вы можете докачать файл.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Вообще.

Это как пытатся прочитать книгу с библиотеки не заходя в библиотеку и не взяв ее в руки :)

Если тебе нужно файл прочитать -- его нужно скачать в любом случае.

Хотя бы как временный файл или скачать файл в оперативную память.